# How to multiply two 8 bit numbers using shift and add operations in 8085 microprocessor?

Tags: binary, 8085

We are supposed to multiply two 8 bit numbers using shift and add operations of 8085 microprocessor. Answer should be a 16 bit number. Use of shift and add operation is compulsory

Comment: Should be fairly easy to find strategies using Google, such as https://www.tutorialspoint.com/8085-program-to-multiply-two-8-bit-numbers-shift-and-add-method What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the solution you must be familiar with Rotate instructions in 8085,particularly for this solution you need to understand two things

1. RRC instruction rotates bits to the right and LSB can be checked from carry flag
2. multiplying number by 2(10 in binary) results in left shif by one bit (verify yourself)
3. adding number with itself is equivaent to multiplying number by 2(10 in binary) and hence also shift bits by 1 bit

   ```
    #ORG 8000
     //initializing operands
            LXI H,7000H   //data is stored in 7000H
            MOV E,M
            MVI D,00H
            INX H
            MOV A,M
            MVI C,08H
            LXI H, 0000H

    //multiplication algorithm starts here
    LOOP :  RRC          
            JNC SKIP
            DAD D

    //left shift is performed by adding number with itself
    //three lines just below this comment is shifting DE pair to left by 1 bit
    SKIP:   XCHG          //exchange HL and DE pair
            DAD H         //Add HL with itself and store in HL
            XCHG          //exchange HL and DE
            DCR C
            JNZ LOOP
            SHLD 7050H
            HLT      
    #ORG7000
    #DB 25,2A
   ```

Comment: The exchange oprations are not required if you use a left shift instead of a right shift. Moreover we can terminate early by checking when the second operand hits zero after a (proper) right shift.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to multiply two integers `27` and `23`. Since `23` (`10111` in binary) can be written as
`2*11 + 1 = 2*(2*5 + 1) + 1 = ... = 2*(2*(2*(2*(2*0 + 1) + 0) + 1) + 1) + 1`. Thus, `x * 23` can be expressed as: `2*(2*(2*(2*(2*0 + x) + 0) + x) + x) + x`. Observe that the addend terms in each step follows the binary representation of `23` (`1`, `0`, `1`, `1`, `1`). With this observation, we can write the following pseudocode to perform the multiplication `x * y` using shift and add operations.

```
let x be the first operand and y be the second one
set sum = 0
repeat
    set sum = sum * 2
    left shift y by one place
    if the overflow bit after the shift is set then
        set sum = sum + x
until y ≠ 0
output the sum as the result of x*y
```

Let `x=27` (`0x1B`) and `y=23` (`0x17`) be two 8-bit intergers, the follwing microprogram performs the required multiplication. As the multiplication may require 16 bits to store the result we use the `HL` register pair for the calculation.

```
      LXI D,001BH ; DE <- 27(x)
      MVI A,17H   ; A <- 23(y)
      LXI H,0000H ; HL <- 0(sum)
      
LOOP: DAD H       ; sum <- sum*2

      STC
      CMC         ; clear the carry flag before rotate
      RAL         ; y <- y<<1

      JNC SKIP    ; if overflow bit from y was not set 
      DAD D       ; sum <- sum + x
SKIP: ORA A       ; to update the zero flag
      JNZ LOOP
      HLT
```

The result, `27*23 = 621` (`0x026D`), is available in the `HL` register pair.